# count_calls() function and the return value

Tags: c

im going through an old exam past paper and had this question

```
int c = 0;

int count_calls()
{
    c = c + 1;
    return c;
}
```

Now it asks why would this go wrong i.e. the number of calls counted is incorrect? is it right to say that no matter what c is set to in the count_calls() function it will always be zero due to the fact c is always defined as 0 outside the class? and would changing it to ++c or +CC fix this issue?

Comment: No, global `int`s only get initialized to 0. But it's global, so anything else can change it willy-nilly.

Comment: Ah, +CC is copy-left, isn't it? That's very kind.

Comment: If you call it enough times, it could overflow.

Comment: It competes in functions.

Comment: It's also not thread-safe

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What does that mean?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY is this an example of a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

1. function increments global variable (and it will be correctly incremented by 1 every time the function was called), but when it returns, it creates local copy.
2. in the range of int type, it can count calls
3. generally speaking, it's bad code (it can't be used in parallel)
4. it wouldn't changed with moving to `++c`